# Perl String How to update value of a string/text

Tags: string, perl

How to edit a file using perl. i have file like this, String1=1 and I want to update the value of String1 to 2 like this String1=2..

Comment: Post what you have and I can give suggestions to improve it.

Comment: Please show the Perl code that you have written and explain the problems you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay response here. But i managed to solve the problem. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13971934/2877493) is a good answer to my question. Well of course it needs to be updated from what I want. But basically this helps me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's had to say... but `String1++` may do the trick...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I would have loved to just comment, but I apparently lack sufficient points... thank you for the reminder, Hamad!!