# Open a file and overwrite the file with adjustments and no backup

Tags: perl, file-io

I have the following three lines:

```
rename($file_path, $file_fh.'.bak');
open( my $file_IN_fh, '<' , $file_path.'.bak') || die "die message";
open( my $file_OUT_fh, '>' , $file_path) || die "die message";
```

It works great. It allows me to go through the in file `while(<$file_IN_fh>)`, make a bunch of changes with a script (`s///g`, `if()` to determine if the line stays or not, etc), and write to the out file. In the end I get my edited file and the **file name is unchanged**.

My issue is that I am at a point where I no longer (currently) want the backup files, so I want to replace the code with something similar that won't create the backup file, and comment back and forth the three lines over the years if my needs change.

How do I do this kind of editing in place not from the command line?

Comment: I'm kicking myself because I saw the answer the other day and now I can't find where I found it :(

Comment: You might be thinking of [manipulating `$^I` and `@ARGV`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063835/need-perl-inplace-editing-of-files-not-on-command-line) (and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9232059/168657)).

Comment: If you process line by line (as you should) then you need to write out changed content to another file.  Once you are done, rename that file to the original.  Note `move` from `File::Copy` for this.

Comment: By the way, `open($fh, $mode, $path)` should be used instead of `open($fh, $mode . $path)`

Comment: @mob, I think that use a temporary backup like the OP's code now (to avoid losing data if a failure occurs).

Comment: Not as far as you know ;)  And whether that matters or not depends on whether OP just wants to not worry about a backup file or whether OP wants to literally not create a backup file, even a short-lived one.

Comment: @mob that `$^I` is what I was thinking of that I saw the other day. I didn't remember the local `@ARGV` part but I might be able to make that work.

Comment: @ikegami you are correct about the `,` instead of the `.`. That was a silly typo on my end. Didn't feel like dealing with copy/paste from my VM.

Comment: I just don't want to deal with a backup file. I don't mind if one is made temporarily. I'm considering just keeping what I have and deleting the backup file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One basic way is to read the file line by line and write desired output lines to a temporary file, which is then renamed so to overwrite the original.

```
use File::Copy qw(move);

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open $outfile: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    next if /line_to_skip/;
    s/patt/repl/g;
    print $fh_out $_;
}
close $_ for ($fh, $fh_out);

move ($outfile, $file) or die "Can't move $outfile to $file: $!";
```

This is what is normally done by tools that edit files "in place" (with additional safety, checks, and flexibility). Since the `$outfile` is temporary use [File::Temp](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html).
Add checks when [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html)-ing files. 
Note that this changes the file's inode number, which may matter for some applications.<sup>†</sup>

If the file isn't huge you can simplify this and read it in first

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @lines = <$fh>;

open    $fh, '>', $file or die "Can't open $file for writing: $!";

for (@lines) {
    next if /line_to_skip/;
    s/patt/repl/g;
    print $fh_out $_;
}

close $fh;
```

what preserves the inode number, since `>` mode truncates the existing inode data.

---

<sup>†</sup> If this is indeed a problem, you can still keep the same inode. After the temporary file is written, open it for reading and open the original file for *writing*; that truncates the contents of that inode.  Then copy the temporary file to the original. Close handles and delete the temporary file.

Comment: I had the code in your second code block earlier. It might sound silly but I didn't like that I was looping through a variable @lines rather than <$fh>. I like the first code block you have.

Comment: @noah  Not silly -- that is a "normal" way to do it; you write as you're ready, with only one line in memory at a time.  The other way is a little simpler, offers more latitude for edits (if needed!) since you have the whole file on hand, and keeps the same inode (I'm adding a note on this).  But I'd consider the first way a bit of a "default."

Answer (score 2):

If the file is huge, then I'd question why you'd want to avoid the temporary file. Otherwise, I'd suggest just loading the file into memory, make modifications, then write it back out.

```
use File::Slurp qw( read_file write_file );

my $in = read_file($qfn, array_ref => 1);

my @out;
while (defined( $_ = shift(@$in) )) {
   s/a/b/g;               # For example.
   push @out, $_ if /c/;  # For example.
}    

write_file($qfn, \@out);
```

I avoided using expensive `splice` by using two arrays.

Note that using Tie::File might save one line of code, but this will be 30x faster<sup>[1]</sup>, and probably use less memory (despite memory-saving being Tie::File's goal). Tie::File is never the answer!!!

---

1. This is not necessarily representative of all Tie::File uses, but I have indeed timed Tie::File taking 30x longer than the alternative at some basic task. That means that 2 seconds worth of work would have taken 1 minute with Tie::File!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Tie::File`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) module. It is a core module and so shouldn't need installing, and the code is as simple as

```
use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', $filepath or die $!;
```

Thereafter the array `@file` will hold the contents of the file, one line per element, and any changes to the array will be reflected in the file. All array operations such as `push`, `splice`, etc. will work fine

Note that line one of the file is in element zero of the array etc.